# iOS 8 Facebook share link, image and text

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, swift, slcomposeviewcontroller

I want to share a content with an image, an url of my app on store and a caption of image.
I tried to using SLComposeViewController, but it not working on iOS 8.
I tried to using FaceBook share link, but it need an image url.
How can I share image + url + text without any server to store image?
Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [FB policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879354/facebook-is-not-shown-in-uiactivityviewcontroller-but-twitter-does) is not possible to autofill the text of a share sheet using SLComposeViewController or UIActivityViewController. It seems to be still possible to share a link.
The behavior seems to be different if you have the official FB app installed:

- If it is installed you can't add text
- If not you can
  The only solution seems to implement the official library, is really a pity!!

Comment: If using FaceBook Share Link content, how to have image URL if not use third party? thank you!

Comment: Could you elaborate? I didn't get

Comment: I'm try to using FBSKShareLinkContent but it need image's url. Could you give me any solution to do that?

Comment: The Facebook library can share simple images taken from camera roll or inside your app without a URL with FBSKPhoto. I think you should read the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios