# Only prob in Facebook sharing....can you please tell me where I made a mistake?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook-graph-api, uiactivityindicatorview

Problem in facebook text sharing, if share twitter or any social media its working. Where I have I made a mistake, please tell me:

```
NSString *textToShare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Hi stackoverflow;

NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                             UIActivityTypePrint,
                                   UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                  UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                  UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,                                
                                      UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,    
                                       UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];     
           activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

 [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: facebook is not allowing pre compiled text.

Comment: what is your question now

Comment: so please tell me what i do for share my app text on facebook? @DineshGurrapu

Comment: I think there is noway to share text on facebook

Comment: how to share text on facebook? @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: apart from `UIActivityViewController` correct

Comment: it means we can't share any text on facebook? @DineshGurrapu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890747/ios-how-to-share-text-and-image-on-social-networks

Comment: yes see this link

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik this code is working well....only problem in facebook Text share.

Comment: @DineshGurrapu ok brow.... an facebook policies allow pre-populated text only for android people....not for iOS...

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879354/facebook-is-not-shown-in-uiactivityviewcontroller-but-twitter-does

Comment: ok than the solution is  remove facebook from sharing.very bad decision by facebook....its only for latest application...in old version its working Fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **i get the answer from FB...**

See This : [We can't share pre-fill text](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill)