# UIActivityViewController Not Showing Facebook if Facebook App Installed

Tags: ios, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am having an issue with the UIActivityViewController on my apps since I updated to iOS 8.3.  Twitter, Mail, and Messages displays fine, but Facebook is not there.  I have checked my code to ensure that I didn't accidentally list it in an excluded activity, and made sure I am signed in on Facebook within my phone settings.  I can verify that it works on simulator, but not in my phone.  Any ideas what may be going on here?

**UPDATE**

Somehow, it is related to the Facebook app itself.  If I remove Facebook from my iPhone, the option to share via Facebook comes back.  If I reinstall the Facebook app, I can no longer share to Facebook.  Any ideas why this is doing it?

```
-(IBAction) invite {
    NSCalendar* gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
    NSDateComponents* theDateComponents = [gregorian components: NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate: [NSDate date]];
    NSInteger weekDay = theDateComponents.weekday;
    if ( weekDay == 1 || weekDay >= 5 ) {
        NSString *invitation = @"Join me @ Fritch Church of Christ Sunday!  Bible Class @9:45AM Worship @10:45AM & 6:00PM!";

        NSArray *activityItems = @[invitation];

        UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[ UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                              UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                              UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                              UIActivityTypePrint ];

        if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
        {
            UIPopoverController* aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityVC];
            [aPopover presentPopoverFromRect:[invite frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
        }
        else {

            [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
    else {
        NSString *invitation = @"Join me @ Fritch Church of Christ this Wednesday! Devotional & Bible Class @7!";
        NSArray *activityItems = @[invitation];

        UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[ UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                              UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                              UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                              UIActivityTypePrint ];

        if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
        {
            UIPopoverController* aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityVC];
            [aPopover presentPopoverFromRect:[invite frame] inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
        }
        else {

            [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        }


    }

}
```

From simulator
[image]

From actual iPhone (both are signed into Facebook)[image]

Comment: As I've already mentioned in the post, I am signed in.

Comment: What version of iphone you used for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the latest Facebook iOS app update embeds an app extension which takes precedence over the Apple native Facebook extension.

Indeed, I could see it because on both cases (Facebook app installer or not) the `NSString *activityType` given by the `UIActivityViewController` completion block is `com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToFacebook` which matches the const string `UIActivityTypePostToFacebook`.

I think it explains the behaviour you (and I) encountered.

For your information, I managed to display the Facebook in the `UIActivityViewController` in both cases with the following workaround: providing at least one `NSURL *` item to share.

But it seems that when the Facebook app is installed, other items such as `NSString *` are not taken into account :(

It is likely to be a Facebook app issue and I hope it will be fixed in future app releases so we can have the same behaviour whether the Facebook app is installed or not.

**EDIT (May 22 2015)**

I am afraid it is not an issue given Facebook terms: see DeepFriedTwinkie's answer on a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30020929/2743762

**EDIT (May 27 2015)**

The current Facebook app (v 31.0) fixes the problem