# Can't add title and description in facebook Share

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, facebook, share

I am trying to implement the Facebook Share in my quiz app. The content is app store link and quiz score.Which is working fine in simulator but in device shows in different and not showing my description. Here is my Code

```
    func ShareFB() {
    let fbVC = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    fbVC?.setInitialText("Hey! I scored \(String(describing: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "TOTAL_SCORE")!)) in Test. This is really interesting! You can also try.")
    fbVC?.add(URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/test-app/i?ls=1&mt=8"))
    fbVC?.add(UIImage(named: "AppIcon"))
    present(fbVC!, animated: true) { _ in

    }
}
```

also attaching screen Shot of simulator and device.
[image: Screenshot of Simulator]

[image: Screenshot of device]

Comment: it's bug from facebook. if you install app in your device then not display any kind of text.

Comment: first remove app from device  then check

Comment: Ok but that's not the correct way.

Comment: Ya i know it's fb bug

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `UIActivityController` for such functionality?

**Example**:

```
    let shareItems = [
        "Hey! I scored \(String(describing: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "TOTAL_SCORE")!)) in Test. This is really interesting! You can also try.",
        URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/test-app/i?ls=1&mt=8"),
        UIImage(named: "AppIcon")] //Add the items you want to share in this array

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)

    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Edit:**

Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30020929/5716829

Comment: yah i tried but getting the same result. not showing my description in device.

Answer (score 0):

now you cannot share image, text and url simultaneously in facebook. also Facebook does not allow pre filled text now

Comment: ok but i want to know one more thing, in game applications how they   share the highest scores ? thanks for your answer

Comment: They either use the Scores/Achievements API, or they create individual URLs for each result that serve the right OG meta data to show the result in title/description/thumbnail ...

Answer (score 0):

According to Facebook's 2.3 policy rules, you can't share pre-filled content because of policy violation. Facebook does not allow you to share the pre-filled user message parameters with any content the user didn't entered himself.

If you want to share content on Facebook then user has to write/enter himself in Facebook prompt message dialog.

For more info, please visit: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill