# Xamarin.ios share does not parse all data for Facebook

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, share

I tried to parse text data (containing strings and a link) for share, the thing is that for anything other than Facebook it sends the data as expected, but for the Facebook it does only parse the links.

Here's my code used for the share:

```
var item = NSObject.FromObject("Hello World !" + "\r\n" + "http://www.google.com");
            var activityItems = new NSObject[] { item };
            UIActivity[] applicationActivities = null;

            var activityController = new UIActivityViewController(activityItems, applicationActivities);

            PresentViewController(activityController, true, null);
```

Comment: According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854282/uiactivityviewcontroller-for-facebook-not-showing-default-text). It seems facebook refuses developers to pre-fill posts with text. You can try to use SDK.

Comment: Okay I got it thank you.